# How to change the value of a 'zeros' matrix in sympy

Tags: python, sympy

I want to change the value of some zeros in my matrix created with the `zeros()` function:

```
import sympy as sp

my_matrix = sp.zeros(3,4)
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(4):
        my_matrix[i][j] += 1
```

Which yields:

```
TypeError: 'Zero' object does not support indexing
```

How can I change their value? Or alternatively, how can I create a matrix (which I can manipulate) full of zeros? Is a for loop the only way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close, you need to index using `[i, j]`. [More about sympy indexing](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/matrices/matrices.html#basic-manipulation).

```
In [16]: matrix = sp.zeros(3,4)

In [17]: for i in range(3):
    ...:     for j in range(4):
    ...:         matrix[i,j] += 1
    ...:

In [18]: matrix
Out[18]:
Matrix([
[1, 1, 1, 1],
[1, 1, 1, 1],
[1, 1, 1, 1]])
```